# Send a simple json from node.js to index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

This should be a simple solution but when I Google it everyone seems to miss this. I want to send a simple json message/file to my index.html

Node.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req,res){
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));


}); 

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res, next) {
res.json({ message: 'Hello World' });
});

app.use('/', router);
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

console.log('Running at Port 3000');
```

Now inside my javascript  code I have

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
complete: function(data) {
console.log(data);   <---------THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE JSON TO BE I 
WANT TO LOG 
IT

}
});
```

How come my Json message doesn't show up??? How can I get this data and console.log it. I appreciate any help I can get on this. I am using Express.

Comment: I'm confused, are you using your default route to both serve your html, and also to return json data to ajax? Why not separate them.

Comment: well, i don't see any issue with your code, do you not get anything in the log? also, if remove your sendfile

Comment: @SpeedOfRound Sorry for the confusion. But what I want to do is send the json to my ajax, so that I can CONSOLE.LOG it

Comment: @SunilLama I Can't CONSOLE.LOG the json

Comment: @MattQuaine, i just ran your code and it is giving me the log...

Comment: @MattQuaine I'm not sure if it's related to your actual issue, but having route return both an html file and a json response is unintuitive, and I'd recommend splitting them into two different routes.

Comment: @SunilLama when you click inspect in Google, Chrome, you see the output?

Comment: @MattQuaine, yes i can..

Comment: @SunilLama this is super strange, look at my edited version of the question, can you still get the log?

Comment: @MattQuaine, now its not good, you cannot have `/index.html` as your route point

Comment: @SunilLama Please tell me how I can log res.json({ message: 'Hello World' }); in HTML

Comment: @MattQuaine, whatever code you had before run it first, then go to browser and hit `localhost:3000/` , what do you get

Comment: @SunilLama That object that you were able to log, was a nested object but it did not have the data, how to put that in json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208732/discussion-between-matt-quaine-and-sunil-lama).

Comment: @SpeedOfRound How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Having the following two snippits incorrectly implemented leads me to believe the OP doesn't fully understand routes, routers and an Express app.

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
}); 

app.get('/index.html', function(req, res, next) {
    res.json({ message: 'Hello World' });
});
```

A router is used to define accessable routes which are expected to return useful information. An Express app then uses that router to serve requests appropriately.

To define a route that will return 'hello world' to your axios request you want to rewrite your route to:

```
router.get('/',  (req, res) => {
    res.json({message: 'hello world'})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [Express CORS Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) and do not experience this issue.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',function(req, res){
  res.json({foo: 'bar'});

}); 

app.use(cors())
app.use('/', router);
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

console.log('Running at Port 3000');
```

You can also explicitly set some AJAX options for jQuery.ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  type: 'GET', 
  complete: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```

You might also try the `success` option for jQuery.ajax.

Comment: Have you tried using Postman (https://postman.com) to see if the request works first? Then, can you show what your browser's developer tools say is the error? In Chrome this is `CTRL + SHIFT + I` > Network > XHR.

Comment: NOOOOOO THAT DOES NOT SOLVE MY PROBLEM

Comment: It is definitely the correct steps to identify your problem. Highly recommend checking out Postman to test your API endpoints outside the browser first, then next test in the browser with Developer Tools. Otherwise you are operating blind.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your code from:

```
res.send({"foo": "bar"});
```

to

```
res.json({"foo": "bar"});
```

Comment: I made the change IT DID NOT WORK BUT THANKS

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Miaplacidus server code and ajax call both working fine, but in case i added data format type json as below.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  data: {
    format: 'json'
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  type: 'GET'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something here but try

```
app.get('/index.html', function(req, res, next) {
res.json({ message: 'Hello World' }).end();
});
```

and in the $.ajax request make sure its a GET request and the url is complete

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/index.html',
  type: 'GET', 
  complete: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
});
```